# Why the UINavigationBar Background Image is Repeating?

Tags: ios

The image size is 640 X 44 and it is for the iPad Portrait. For some reason it is displaying as a pattern image instead of stretched.

[image]

iOS 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that ipad's resolution is 1024x768.Thus, the width of your image should be 768

Comment: oh man!! You are right! Why was I thinking 640 pts heheh :) and it is now fixed!! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

try the following to stretch your image:

```
// load the background image navbar.png
UIImage *imageNavBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"];

// set the image as stretchable and set into navbar globally
imageNavBar = [imageNavBar stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:imageNavBar forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: This is also totally working if your background image has transparent parts. Even if your background does not exceeds the navigationbar width, you can see that it repeats itself via transparent parts. Great solution...

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 1):

One way is to resize your image according to the width of navigation bar.

```
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "top_header_iPhone")
let navimg = navBackgroundImage.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: navBackgroundImage.size.height))

UINavigationBar .appearance().setBackgroundImage(navimg, for:.default)

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "FightingSpiritturbo", size: 23)!]
```

And the function for resizing image is:

```
extension UIImage{

    func resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let horizontalRatio = newSize.width / size.width
        let verticalRatio = newSize.height / size.height

        let ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```