# UINavigationBar Background Image Repeats Itself

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am setting a background image on the uinavigationbar, but the image is repeating itself. I don't want that the image repeats itself. Can anyone help me in this.

Here is the code for setting the background image:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Image_Name")), for: .default)
```

Here is the screenshot of my navigation bar:
[image]

See the circled portion, there is a line in between and after that line the image starts repeating itself.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the UINavigationBar Background Image is Repeating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986730/why-the-uinavigationbar-background-image-is-repeating)

Comment: Maybe you should provide image in different aspect ratio?

Answer (score 4):

Set resizable image with resizing mode. try this code.

```
let image = //your image
let barImage = image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero, resizingMode: .stretch)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(barImage, for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
let barImage = yourUIImage.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 0, topCapHeight: 0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(barImage, for: .default)
```